# Publishing a port in gitlab-ci-runner using docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to specify in a gitlab runner that I want my docker image, when running, to publish port 8000. I did not find anything in the gitlab documentation that shows how to do it.

Docker says that it should be specified in the command line, when docker runs, but I have no clue how to do that from within a gitlab runner configuration.

Any ideas?

This is my gitlab runner configuration

```
[[runners]]
  name="gitlab.foo.com"
  url = "http://gitlab.foo.com/ci"
  token = "23foo"
  executor = "docker"
 [runners.docker]
  tls_verify = false
  image = "foo/laravel"
  privileged = false
  disable_cache = false
  volumes = ["/cache"]
  extra_hosts = ["foo:192.168.1.22"]
```

My docker image exposes port 8000

Answer (score 1):

I found that the gitlab-ci-runner using docker should be used for build docker images, or just run some app in a container.

so we can't use that to run a container to publish a port .

I found some something [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#accessing-the-services)